I am using Gmail API and Recently I got Mail From Google About Actions to take to apps using "email reporting and monitoring"
Problem
Under "Your restricted scopes" I am using "./auth/gmail.modify" scope and it has
"What features will you use?" Under that I have selected

Email Productivity
Email Reporting and Monitoring

Because i am trying to use Read Customer Mailbox reading all the messages and marking them as read.
My understanding is
Email reporting and monitoring -> Marking emails as read or unread
Email productivity -> Read the email data
And my app is verified long time and i have few users using it.
I want to understand did my understand correct.
If I uncheck now "Email reporting and monitoring" then my App will into verifcication process and will impact the current users.
I want to understand is it safe to uncheck and went to verification process again ? any one know please help
Deadline is June 3rd. Currently for now i am handling "Inavlid_grant" option and trying to send mail to users saying that "App expired please Reauthenticate"
Or any Google Contact I can reach out ?
